# Read input in c++

Tags: c++, scanf, stdio

Im very new to c++ and trying to take my first steps. In my problem I need to read 3 integers and do something with it. So, to take this integers I wrote:

```
int a, b, n;
scanf("%i%i\n", &a, &b);
scanf("%i", &n);
```

and also I tried:

```
scanf("%i%i", &a, &b);
scanf("%i", &n);
```

but he always gives me some random large integer for n.
input:

```
7 13
1
```

ty

if I write

```
freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

int a, b, n;
cin >> a >> b;
cin >> n;
printf("%i", n);
return 0;
```

It doesnt work. As same as

```
freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

int a, b, n;
scanf("%i%i", &a, &b);
scanf("%i", &n);    
printf("%i", n);
return 0;
```

Comment: Think `%d` for *digit* or *decimal*.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's misleading and implies that `%d` will consume just `4` if the input were `"42"`. `%d` means *decimal* (base-10).

Comment: Any reason for not using <iostream>?  Then you could easily std::cin >> a >> b >> n;

Comment: Your code is actually working for me.

Comment: @0x499602D2 For the values he shows, there's no difference between `%d` and `%i`.  (`%i` will accept `0xa`; `%d` won't.)

Comment: Why the `freopen`?  And does it succeed?  (In practice, there's almost never any reason to use `freopen`, and `std::ifstream` doesn't even offer the possibility.)

Comment: Hint: always check return value of `scanf`. Also, try to initialize variables when defining them, to avoid accidentally using them uninitialized (especially when learning and unsure of what some code actually does).

Comment: Sorry to sound pedantic, but was your input "7<space>13<enter>1<enter>"?  @hyde is correct, test the return values of each `scanf()` which should be 2 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way one inputs integers in C++.  Try:

```
std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

But if you want two on the first line, and the third on
a separate line, you might want to read line by line (using
`std::getline`):

```
std::string line;
std::getline( std::cin, line );
std::istringstream l1( line );
l1 >> a >> b >> std::ws;
if ( !l1 || l1.get() != EOF ) {
    //  The line didn't contain two numbers...
}
std::getline( std::cin, line );
std::istringstream l2( line );
l2 >> n >> std::ws;
if ( !l2 || l1.get() != EOF ) {
    //  The second line didn't contain one number...
}
```

This will allow much better error detection and recovery
(assuming the input format is line oriented).

You should probably forget about `scanf`.  It's very hard to use
correctly, and not very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, is there a reason you are not using streams?

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
std::cin >> n;
```

To read from a file, you will use an std::ifstream.

```
std::ifstream file( "filename.txt" );
if( file.is_open() )
{
    file >> a >> b >> n;
    file.close();
}
```

cppreference.com is a good reference: [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Comment: I need to get an input from file

Comment: @Dima So you an `std::ifstream`.  Anything you can to with `std::cin`, you can do with any `std::istream`.

Comment: @Dima If you're getting input from a file, then why are you using `scanf` at all instead of `fscanf`? (Both are pretty notoriously hard to use, however. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)